# LOG4J call only for specific function

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log-level

asking this as an experiences Log4j user:

We have a pretty big class with lots of debug statements (`Logger.getLogger(class).debug("Borrowed connection "+con.getId()`)... you know what I mean :)

Now I suspect one specific function to not work as expected and I want only this one particular function to log the debug output, the rest of the Class should keep the "error" level.

is there a solution to this? Google wouldn't satisfy my this time :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an own loger per method even though that may be a little inconvenient.

```
Logger.getLogger(class.getName()+"#methodName").debug(..)
```

will allow to define the log lever per method.

Comment: Should be ".methodName" to allow the configuration to filter out just the one method.